# QEMU consuming lot CPU on emulating ARM

Tags: arm, raspberry-pi3, qemu

I'm writing an operating system for learning purposes, I'm focusing on the raspberry pi3 as target machine. To test my code I decided to use QEMU to emulate the raspberry hardware. By the way, the question in not about raspberry, but about ARM emulation in general or what is the standard behaviour of QEMU. The problem is that when I launch my kernel with the command:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -M raspi3 -monitor stdio -d in_asm -kernel kernel8.img
```

I have 4 cores of my host machine (x86_64 running linux) at 100% of usage.

to be more precise, my kernel is not a kernel at all! It's just 2 lines of assembly of what will be the bootloader for the kernel:

```
.section ".text.boot"

.global _start

_start:
1:      wfi
        b 1b
```

So I don't think the problem is in the code. Here the dump of the kernel8.elf

```
~> aarch64-elf-objdump -d kernel8.elf

kernel8.elf:     file format elf64-littleaarch64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000080000 <__start>:
   80000:       d503207f        wfi
   80004:       17ffffff        b       80000 <__start>
```

also trying to change machine, such raspi2 or versatilepb doesn't help much, CPU usage is lower but still high (on average 70%). Using the generic ARM emulation "-M virt" reduces more the CPU usage, but still have one core always at 100% and the others at about 50%.

Is this normal?? Does emulating ARM on x86 require such a lot of CPU usage, taking into account the extreme simplicity of the code I'm emulating??

Comment: I suspect WFI executes as a NOP, so you are running an infinite loop with 100% MCU utiization. have a look here: http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361289926427.htm

Comment: Hence actually QEMU tells to the processor to execute NOP instead of halting the cores... and this causes the processor to execute such infinite loop, causing the 100% CPU usage. But shouldn't instructions like WFI or WFE be translated in x86 equivalent instructions like HLT?? Can I have some way to fix this??

Comment: I would have started with a working image, and only after setup is validated, start working on the code

Comment: There is no architectural requirement to implement WFI as anything other than a no-op. As it happens, QEMU *does* implement WFI as "put this virtual CPU to sleep until there's something to do" (https://git.qemu.org/?p=qemu.git;a=blob;f=target/arm/op_helper.c;h=8ee15a4bd45dd381b2d7a458f558c94dd571b66d;hb=HEAD#l428) so the chances are high there's something wrong with your setup. Either execution is not getting to your code at all and is spinning somewhere else, or else there's an active interrupt and so WFI never goes to sleep. Try using the -d debug options to see what's happening.

Comment: the emulator of a foreign instruction set is not going to directly translate to the native instruction set, it is going to simply run an emulation, some code, high level language most likely, that picks the instructions apart and emulates them using emulated registers and memory and the like.  Even though the instruction might be a wfi or wfe which shouldnt cause execution ideally, there is still a system, there are peripherals to emulate of which one/some might be the thing that eventually frees the core.

Comment: even if YOU might happen to know that there is nothing you setup to cause an interrupt for the core to be freed and continue execution, the emulator might not be that smart it is likely emulating every clock tick with some optimizations of all the peripherals.  and, that emulation will consume a host processor, the code might be written to have a few places if any where it yields to the operating system.

Comment: processors are never really idle (some mcu rare exceptions but those arent completely idle either) the graphs and numbers we quote are simply dividing this code from that, spending most of the time in kernel code being considered not using the cpu but running in application mode being measured as busy.  on my x86 I have a line of code for(x=0;;x++) continue; which consumes 100% of a host cpu core while running.  no different here it is that trivial to write a program that does that now try to emulate a system like the raspberry pi and make it perform, you should easily consume a core.

Comment: thanks all of you! I've not resolved the problem, but I can run the code without no overhead for the host CPU... I don't know why, but if I launch QEMU without passing the .img (that is kernel8.img) but passing directly the .elf file (kernel8.elf) there is no QEMU overhead on the host system, and the emulation gets halted at the wfi instruction (see it by using -d in_asm) as expected

Comment: now the problem is to figure out why by executing ```aarch64-elf-objcopy -O binary kernel8.elf kernel8.img``` I get an image file which is in some way wrong...

Comment: QEMU handles ELF and .img files differently for the -kernel option on Arm boards. ELF files are treated as "bare metal", which usually means "run them directly with all guest CPUs at once". img files are treated as "Linux kernel images", which are booted in the way that the Linux kernel boot protocol specifies that images are supposed to be booted (usually only with one CPU, secondary CPUs being penned up via a board-specific boot protocol.) You need to use whichever file type is correct for how your code expects to be started.

Comment: Thank you a lot @PeterMaydell! I was completely unaware of this... now my doubts are solved, since I'm doing bare metal programming, I'll go for ELF file. Thank you again!